# Android Studio how to add background from JPG or image?

Tags: android-layout, android-activity

Please just to let you know I am super noob at this but I am a VB6 and VB.net programmer and have some skills in HTML and little PHP so this stuff is a start and I am liking it already.

1. How do I add a background image on activity1?
2. How to exit the application with a click of a button and then give a bye message?
3. Is there a way to free move objects such as buttons, listview etc on the activity design page? Freemove with mouse, it seems to move away when I unclick the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

1. The layout xml file will have a main layout.  you can set the background attribute of this layout.
2. Android apps don't do this. Users don't expect it either.  Generally a user will hit the home button or the back button - read the activity lifecycle docs on how to handle this in your app:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

3. Using the visual design tools in Android Studio may be confusing at first.  It will depend on what type of layout you are trying to move objects in.  Have you read the getting started docs?

https://developer.android.com/training/index.html